# pig how to concat columns into single string

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a column of strings that I load using Pig:

```
A
B
C
D
```

how do I convert this column into a single string like this?

```
A,B,C,D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to first `GROUP ALL` to put everything into one bag, then join the contents of the bag together using a UDF. Something like this:

```
-- myudfs.py
-- #!/usr/bin/python
-- 
-- @outputSchema('concated: string')
-- def concat_bag(BAG):
--     return ','.join(BAG)
Register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myfuncs;

A = LOAD 'myfile.txt' AS (letter:chararray) ;

B = GROUP A ALL ;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE myfuncs.concat_bag(A.letter) AS all_letters ;
```

If your file/schema contains multiple columns, you are probably going to want to project out the column you want to generate the string for. Something like:

```
A0 = LOAD 'myfile.txt' AS (letter:chararray, val:int, extra:chararray) ;
A = FOREACH A0 GENERATE letter ;
```

This way you are not keeping around extra columns that will slow down an already expensive operation.